# list of netlogo slider values

Tags: list, slider, netlogo

I am trying to create a list (just within my function) of the values from 10 sliders (each ranging 0-100, named num_strain_0 to num_strain_9).

currently, within one of my functions, I have:

```
let ten_strain_list [num_strain_0 num_strain_1 num_strain_2 num_strain_3 
num_strain_4 num_strain_5 num_strain_6 num_strain_7 num_strain_8 num_strain_9]
```

I get the following error "Expected a literal value"
Is there a way to return (report?) the current value of a slider and make the list work?

Comment: can you show the implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netlogo is saying that that style of list building works for constant values, not reporters or interface widgets. Instead, I think you want the `list` primitive:

```
let three_train_list ( list num_strain_0 num_strain_1 num_strain_2 )
```

Note that the parentheses here are necessary as there are more than two desired list items. For more information, check out the explanation in the [programming guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#lists) regarding **Building Lists on the Fly** or the [list](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#list) dictionary entry.